# Creating a bar plot from summarySE result table with multiple group variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a result table from the `summarySE` function:

```
    a        b N               variable   sd    se   ci
 1234      foo 264                  2.0 0.87 0.053 0.11
 1234      bar 111                  3.6 1.35 0.128 0.25
 5678      foo 169                  1.8 1.02 0.079 0.16
 5678      bar 118                  1.6 1.13 0.104 0.21
91011      foo   9                  1.3 1.35 0.450 1.04
91011      bar 384                  1.0 1.12 0.057 0.11
```

I want to create a bar plot, where each row corresponds to a bar, its height being `variable` – so I need `stat="identity"`. Now, usually, I would have no problem doing this:

```
column = "varaible"
ggplot(data, aes_string(y = column)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

But it fails with:

```
Error during wrapup: argument "env" is missing, with no default
```

Of course, because there are multiple columns defining what `x` is. If I do

```
ggplot(data, aes_string(x = "a", y = column)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

It works for unique values of `a`, but it does not consider `b`. How do I consider both combinations of `a` and `b` as x values?

Comment: you want them x-labeled as `paste`d together `a` and `b` as cathegorical axis?

Comment: @lukeA Why don't you post that as an answer? Worked nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use another aesthetic like fill

```
ggplot(data, aes_string(x = "a", fill = "b", y = column)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

or concatenate both columns

```
ggplot(transform(data, t = paste(a, b)), 
       aes_string(x = "t", y = column)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```